# whats wrong with this JS?

Tags: javascript

There is any interesting [article](http://www.fitzblog.com/2007/08/nine-javascript-gotchas) which warns about JS problems.

However, notice #2:

```
<input type="button" value="Gotcha!" id="MyButton" >
<script>
var MyObject = function () {
    this.alertMessage = "Javascript rules";
    this.ClickHandler = function() {
          alert(this.alertMessage );
      }
}();

</script>
```

Notice the self executing function by `()` at the end. However I'm pretty sure the `this.xxx` is used when doing `new MyObject()`. He wrote :

> If you call `MyObject.ClickHandler();` you will get a popup saying "Javascript rules".

and his sample doesn't work. I've tried `MyObject.ClickHandler()` and got an error...(Cannot call method 'ClickHandler' of undefined)

How can I make `MyObject.ClickHandler()` work ?

Comment: "got an error" - which error? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `new` keyword. Currently, `this` refers to `window` and `ClickHandler` is available through `window.ClickHandler`.

When using the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) keyword, a new object is created and the `this` keyword will refer to that newly created object. That is why the `ClickHandler` method will be added to `MyObject` below:

```
var MyObject = new (function () {
    this.alertMessage = "Javascript rules";
    this.ClickHandler = function () {
        alert(this.alertMessage);
    };
})();
```

Be careful when doing something like:

```
document.getElementById("MyButton")
    .addEventListener("click", MyObject.ClickHandler, false);
```

`addEventListener` makes `this` refer to the object on which the event listener was assigned. See also [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for changing the `this` scope.

Comment: my friend , thats what i wrote !!! it should have `new`. so he has errors n his sample....right ?

Comment: You don't need the `()` around `function(){}`, but it may make it nicer to read.

Comment: @Rocket so why did he write () at the end ? he was trying to execute the function. but it wont help much.... the function need to be instanced....right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir If you intend to make `this` refer to anonymous function that you have just created, yes.

Comment: @Lekensteyn it can be also for non-anonymous : `function aa(){};  new aa();`....right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir When creating a new object with `this`, you usually use sth like `var date = new Date()`. In this answer, you first create a new function (that replaces `Date`) and then instantiates it. When there are no params, though you can omit the empty parentheses when using `new`. Yes, non-anonymous functions work as well, but I was referring to the answer in which `this` points to the anonymous function and not, say, the `window` object.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The `()` at the end don't do anything, nor do the `()` around `function(){}`.  You can just do `var a = new function(){}` or `function aa(){}; var a = new aa();`, you can even do `var a = new aa;`.

Comment: @Rocket i know all this stuff....but since i met his code(from the link) - I thought "well , maybe i think i know but im not"..... but it appears he has an errors in his code....right ?\

Comment: @Rocket p.s. didnt know i can remove the () in parmeterless ctor. ( is it working in all browsers ?)

Comment: @Lekensteyn regaring the last part  - i use `var self=this`. I will love to hear what your solution for this. :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `var a = new aa;` should work in all browsers.  As for `var self = this;`, that's usually the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Zoiks, Lekensteyn hit the nail on the head. I didn't fully understand what you were intending to accomplish here...

---

That is not exactly a "self-executing function." If you had built it like this:

```
(function(MyObject) {
    MyObject.alertMessage = "Javascript rules";
    MyObject.ClickHandler = function() {
        alert(this.alertMessage );
    }
})(window.MyObject = window.MyObject || {});
```

Then I would call it a self-executing function.

Once you've done that, now you could execute `MyObject.ClickHandler()` and get the alert.